# How to add a new Node on Kendo treeview with remote datasource

Tags: c#, jquery, kendo-ui, treeview

Here is the code for my Kendo Treeview. I am unable to add a new Node for the selected Node.

```
function treeView() {
var treeMenu = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
    schema: {
        data: function (response) {
                    return JSON.parse(response.d);
                   },
        schema: {
            model: {
                hasChildren: true,
                id: "id",
                children: "HasChildren",
                hasChildren: "HasChildren",
                fields: {
                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: false, type: "string" },
                    LINK: { editable: true, nullable: true, type: "string" },
                },
            }
        }
    },
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "/getTest",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
        },
        parameterMap: function (data, type) {
            if ((type == "read") || (type == "update") || (type == "create") || (type == "destroy")) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);

            } else {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: treeMenu,
    loadOnDemand: false,
    expanded: true,
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataTextField: ['LINK'],
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
 }).data("kendoTreeView");}
```

Code for Add:

```
function addNode(curr) {
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
console.log('currObj = ' + currObj);
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
var selectedNode = $(currObj);
if (selectedNode.length == 0) {
    selectedNode = null;
}

var LABEL=prompt("Please enter desired Node name","Default");

if (LABEL == null) {
    return;
}

treeview.append(LABEL, selectedNode);
```

}

Getting error after entering the Node as "TypeError: o is undefined".  can anyone help me this.

Thanks